# Interactively deleting files from a list

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, rm

I'd like to remove a list of files and be asked for confirmation. The list is in the `list.txt` file. Why the following command doesn't work properly?

```
while read i; do rm -i $i; done < list.txt
```

The previous command doesn't wait for me but fortunately no file is deleted.

I'm using Bash.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`rm -i` reads its answer from standard input, which it inherits from the `while` loop. So a line of text from `list.txt` is being used as the answer to the "really remove?" question. To fix, you'll need to separate the two sources of input. The easiest way is to have `read` take its input from a separate file descriptor:

```
while IFS= read <&3 -r i; do
  rm -i -- "$i"     # Quote the file name, not just to be safe,
                    # but because it's the right syntax.
done 3< list.txt
```

You are no longer redirecting standard input (fd 0) for the while loop, so `rm` will read from the terminal as desired.

Alternatively, you could have done:

```
IFS=$'\n' # set field separator to newline
set -f    # disable globbing upon command substitution
rm -i -- $(cat list.txt)
```

Or, with GNU xargs:

```
xargs -rd '\n' --arg-file=list.txt rm -i --
```

Comment: So if I had in the list a file named `y`, the previous file would have been deleted?

Comment: Not just `y`, but any name beginning with `y`. Apparently, `rm` just looks at the first character of whatever response it receives: 'y' is yes, anything else is no.

Answer (score 2):

For something a bit fancier than answering yes or no to each file, you could use `iselect` for interactive ncurses-based selection.  e.g.

```
iselect -a -m < list.txt | xargs -d '\n' -r echo rm
```

or to allow selection of files in the current dir:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | iselect -a -m | xargs -d '\n' -r echo rm
```

That will display a full-screen (full-terminal) ncurses-based listing, where files can be selected and de-selected at will by pressing SPACE.  press ENTER to accept your selections (selected entries will be printed on stdout), or `q` to quit (nothing printed to stdout).  press `h` for help.

Note the `echo rm` - i've written it like that for testing.  change it to just `rm` once you're confident you understand what it's doing.

Also note that `xargs` is being used here with `\n` as the input separator.  This will not work if any of the filenames have linefeed characters in them.  For that matter, the `iselect` won't work properly either - it expects one item per line - u nfortunately, `iselect` does not have an option for null-terminated input or output.

`iselect` is packaged for debian, probably ubuntu and other distros too.  home page is at http://www.ossp.org/pkg/tool/iselect/